# updating chosen elements in Pygame

Tags: python, graph, pygame, fft

I am working on animation of Fourier Transform in python, pygame. I want the result to look more or less as following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACvXAjZE9jQ

I need to update the screen in order to constantly draw arms, or links in their new positions. However, updating the screen erases the graph drawn by the arms. I am drawing it by putting small dots in time intervals.

Would anyone have any suggestion how to deal with this dilemma or propose another solution?

My first idea was to add all the points coordinates to the list and draw them all together at every update, but the operation quickly becomes too inefficient and the animation keeps slowing dowm.

Comment: There are many solutions, I suggest you to draw your image (with the Fourier Transform, point by point or line by line) on a Surface and blit it one the screen and then blit the Fourier sctructure (all the circles) on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

> My first idea was to add all the points coordinates to the list and draw them all together at every update

This is the usual approach. However, I suggest converting the coordinates to `int` before adding them to the list, and only adding coordinate tuples that are not already in the list. This means that a new position must be compared with the last position before it is added. With this approach, the list should not become so long that the application slows down significantly. e.g.:

```py
def appendPoint(point_list, x, y):
    new_point = round(x), round(y)
    if not point_list or point_list[-1] != new_point:
        point_list.append(new_point)
```